# Using Cursor to write CSV and Insert into Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to fetch data that both writes csv data to a file, and updates a table with that same record. This cursor could potentially find 100k-300k records.

Is there a more efficient way to do this rather than looping over? I was thinking of doing an insert with a Select outside the loop, but there's no way of knowing that each record was successfully written to file.

```
DECLARE
...

   file_output VARCHAR2 (3000);
   col2 column2%type;
   col3 column3%type;

 CURSOR my_cursor
   IS
    select
      csv_val1 || ',' || csv_val2|| ',' || csv_val3,
      column2,
      column3
    from my_cursor_table

...

BEGIN

...
   FETCH my_cursor INTO file_output,col2,col3;

   WHILE my_cursor%FOUND
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (ID, file_output);
         insert into my_insert_table values(col2,col3);
..

END;
```

Comment: yeah, I don't think there is any way to "rollback" file i/o.  If there was an error, you would have to rollback all the inserts. You could use a savepoint and do it in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- `bulk collect` the query into an array with a limit
- Loop through the array, writing each element to the file
- Wrap the `utl_file` call in an exception handler that logs the error and deletes that element from the array
- Use `forall i in indices of` to only insert the values that succeeded

This should come out notably faster than single row processing. In this simple example processing 100k rows:

- Row-by-row processing was ~15s
- Bulk collect/forall was ~1.5s

So about 10x faster:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int
);

set timing on
declare
  cursor cur is
    select level c1, mod ( level, 10 ) c2
    from   dual
    connect by level <= 100000;
  rec cur%rowtype;
  f utl_file.file_type;
begin
  f := utl_file.fopen ('TMP', 'test.csv', 'w');
  open cur;
  loop
    fetch cur into rec;
    exit when cur%notfound;
    
    begin 
      utl_file.put_line ( f, rec.c1 || ',' || rec.c2 );
      insert into t values ( rec.c1, rec.c2 );
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line( 'Error logging' );
    end;
  end loop;
  close cur;
  utl_file.fclose(f);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:15.192

declare
  cursor cur is
    select level c1, mod ( level, 10 ) c2
    from   dual
    connect by level <= 100000;
  type rec_arr is table of cur%rowtype
    index by pls_integer;
  rec rec_arr;
  f utl_file.file_type;
begin
  f := utl_file.fopen ('TMP', 'test.csv', 'w');
  open cur;
  loop
    fetch cur bulk collect into rec
    limit 100;
    exit when rec.count = 0;
    
    for i in 1 .. rec.count loop
      begin
        utl_file.put_line ( f, rec(i).c1 || ',' || rec(i).c2 );
      exception
        when others then
          dbms_output.put_line( 'Error logging' );
          rec.delete(i);
      end;
    end loop;
    forall i in indices of rec
      insert into t values ( rec(i).c1, rec(i).c2 );
  end loop;
  close cur;
  utl_file.fclose(f);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.578
```

Note this doesn't handle the case where the write succeeds, but the insert fails...

To get around that, You can do something like:

- Insert the rows (with `forall ... save exceptions` or `insert ... log errors`)
- Write the rows that succeeded
- Delete the rows that failed to write to the file